Problem in blender's knife tool
I have a question. I used the blender's knife tool to join two vertex points that weren't connected, and after I did so and verified, I noticed that another line vertex had been formed in the model; I'm not sure why that happened (I checked, and the mirror wasn't on). How should I proceed?
like this image  , i  connected this two vertex points and i made a edge (which i select) and when i look around i see these edge (I drew a line around them)

I have no idea, depends on where that line vertex (whatever that is, is it an edge or a vertex?) appeared and how you did that. Most likely you can select it and press X > Dissolve Edges. But why did you use the Knife tool in the first place? Select the two vertices and press J.

You should add an image to take a look
